# How to change the order of the TabItem in the wpf TabControl

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol, tabitem

I need to change the order of the TabItem.

I've tried with Remove / Insert and it doesn't works.

```
void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  if(condition) {
    TabControl.Items.Remove(TabItem);
      TabControl.Items.Insert(0, TabItem);
    }
}
```

InvalidOperationException:
Element already has a logical parent. It must be detached from the old parent before it is attached to a new one.

How to solve this?

Comment: The code listed above works for me in a regular window (I didn't try a UserControl).  I assume TabItem is the name of the actual TabItem, and not just the TabItem keyword?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved using the "for" instead of "foreach".

```
if(condition) {    
  var tabItem = Tab.Items[index];
  Tab.Items.RemoveAt(index);
  Tab.Items.Insert(0, tabItem);
  ((TabItem)tabItem).IsSelected = true;
}
```

Comment: I was searching for setting my second tab as the selected on in design view. I could not find the property IsSlected in the Properties pane but did it with code and it worked. thanks

Comment: Can you please also tell how can I change order of the tabs in designview (Xaml) (WPF) thanks.