# How to change TabItem indices of a TabControl at runtime?

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol, tabitem

I have five `TabItem`'s in my `TabControl` and I need to move the position of each tab continuously at runtime. Can anyone tell me how can I change tab index from one position to another position at runtime.

Thanks,
@nagaraju.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `ObservableCollection` the you Just have to change the position of the Item in your collection it will be refelected in View...

For Example..

```
<TabControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=listView}"
            ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey=myTabItem}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Persons}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedPerson}"
            Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=myTab}"
            TabStripPlacement="Bottom">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Width="16"
                       Height="16"
                       Margin="0,0,2,0"
                       Source="Themes\Water lilies.jpg" />
                <TextBlock Margin="0,4,0,0"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           FontWeight="Bold"
                           Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
<Button Grid.Row="1" Width="50" Command="{Binding Path=ChangePositionCommand}"> ClickMe </Button>
```

Here you just Change the Position of the item in `TabList` in ViewModel and that Position will be changed accordingly...

## In Your ViewModel

I have the implementation if getting Data and Setting Up Commands... that up to you how you Do it

```
public ICommand ChangePositionCommand { get; private set; }

public Person SelectedPerson
{
    get { return selectedPerson; }
    set
    {
        selectedPerson = value;
        InvokePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedPerson"));
    }
}

private void ChangePosition(object obj)
{
    int index = Persons.IndexOf(SelectedPerson);

    if (index <= (Persons.Count-1))
    {
        Persons.Move(index,index+1);
    }
    else
    {
        Persons.Move(index,0);
    }
}
```

The above code my give `INdex out of bound` but I am no where near an IDE so cant test that you could reapir it according to you.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below solution:

```
TabItem tempTab = new TabItem();
            tempTab = control.Items[0] as TabItem;
            control.Items[0] = control.Items[1];
            control.Items[1] = tempTab;
```

This will definitely work and you have to do from code behind.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `TabControl.Items` Collection. Remove the tab from the old Position and set it on a new Positon.

See [How to change the order of the TabItem in the wpf TabControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043179/how-to-change-the-order-of-the-tabitem-in-the-wpf-tabcontrol)

Comment: in that sample why again inserting at 0 index irrespective of removed index?

Comment: it giving me error 'Element already has a logical parent. It must be detached from the old parent before it is attached to a new one.'